# How to ignore HTTP errors while using requests with for loop?

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, python-requests, python-requests-html

this is my code that checks multiple urls for a specific keyword and writes to the output file if the keyword was found or not.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/input.csv')
urls = df.T.values.tolist()[2]
myList= []

for url in urls:
    url_1 = url
    keyword ='myKeyword'
    res = requests.get(url_1)
    finalresult= print(keyword in res.text)

    if finalresult == False:
        myList.append("NOT OK")
    else:
        myList.append("OK")

df["myList"] = pd.DataFrame(myList, columns=['myList'])

df.to_csv('/path/to/output.csv', index=False)
```

However, once any of my multiple URLs is down and there is an HTTP error the script stops and the following error is displayed:

```
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='argos-yoga.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x122582d90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known'))
```

How can I ignore such errors and let my script continue with the scan? Could someone help me with this? thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to put `try..except` only around `requests.get()` and `res.text`.

For example:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/input.csv')
urls = df.T.values.tolist()[2]
myList= []

for url in urls:
    url_1 = url
    keyword ='myKeyword'
    try:                                    # <-- put try..except here
        res = requests.get(url_1)
        finalresult = keyword in res.text   # <-- remove print()
    except:
        finalresult = False

    if finalresult == False:
        myList.append("NOT OK")
    else:
        myList.append("OK")

df["myList"] = pd.DataFrame(myList, columns=['myList'])

df.to_csv('/path/to/output.csv', index=False)
```

---

EDIT: To put `Down` into the list when there's error:

```
for url in urls:
    url_1 = url
    keyword ='myKeyword'
    try:                                    # <-- put try..except here
        res = requests.get(url_1)

        if keyword in res.text:
            myList.append("OK")
        else:
            myList.append("NOT OK")
    except:
        myList.append("Down")
```

Comment: This works! thank you Andrej. Just wondering, how I could add a flag for HTTP errors. so for example, if this is my URL in the input file 'argos-yoga.com' , I would like to have it marked as 'Down' instead of 'OK ' as the page is not working. Can I add something like this somewhere in your code:     `except Exception as e:
        print(f"There was an error, error = {e}")
        myList("Down")
        pass`
The reason I'm asking is because it would be good to know which URLs throw HTTP errors too and have them saved in my errorLog.txt when I will run this script from terminal. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use the try-except way

Example:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/input.csv')
urls = df.T.values.tolist()[2]
myList= []

for url in urls:
    url_1 = url
    keyword ='myKeyword'
    try:
        res = requests.get(url_1)
        finalresult = keyword in res.text
        print(finalresult)
        if finalresult == False:
            myList.append("NOT OK")
        else:
            myList.append("OK")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"There was an error, error = {e}")
        pass
    df["myList"] = pd.DataFrame(myList, columns=['myList'])
    df.to_csv('/path/to/output.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks Ahmed! I've tried the above code, however it doesn't add 'NOT OK' if finalresult ==False. I get 'OK' for all URLs. would you know how Can I fix this?

Comment: I am not sure, so when final result is equal to False it says OK?

Comment: Ok yeah, I figured it out you need to add finalresult = keyword is res.text
since you just assigned it to a print statement, I edited the code try it and tell me if it worked